# How can i use a proxy server for whois command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, proxy, ftp

Well, my goal is to use a free proxy server to make the whois command requests in the terminal to control the limit of requests by ip and then immediately disable the proxy (I want it to work only for the execution of the whois command in the terminal).

I tried using a .sh file as follows:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
export FTP_PROXY=<IP_ADRESS>:<PORT>
export HTTP_PROXY=<IP_ADRESS>:<PORT>
export HTTPS_PROXY=<IP_ADRESS>:<PORT>

whois domain.com

unset ftp_proxy
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

But, in the request, my original IP is kept in the whois command request and it doesn't work as I need.

I am using Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, the `whois` command uses neither `ftp` nor `http` to connect to remote servers. It uses the `whois` protocol on port 43, and it isn't particularly amendable to proxies.

Modern versions of `whois` may use `http` for *some* remote registries. For example, with the `jwhois` command, the file `/etc/jwhois.conf` instructs it whether it can use http or not for querying a particular server.

This doesn't help you much: because you don't necessarily know in advance what servers it will need to contact, even if it supports proxy access for http queries (and I'm not sure that it does), there would be a good chance it would still need to use the `whois` protocol and thus wouldn't be able to take advantage of your proxy.

A better choice might be to find a service that offers a whois-via-http API. It looks like there are a few out there but I haven't worked with any of them so I can't recommend something in particular.